# How do I extract from a list in python?

Tags: python

If I have a list that is made up of 1MM ids, how would I pull from that list in intervals of 50k?

For example:

```
[1]cusid=df['customer_id'].unique().tolist()
[1]1,000,500
```

If I want to pull in chunks, is the below correct for 50k?

```
cusid=cusid[:50000] - first 50k ids
cusid=cusid[50000:100001] - the next 50k of ids
cusid=cusid[100001:150001] - the next 50k
```

are my interval selections correct?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks about right (note that the ending boundary is always exclusive, so you can just do `[:50k]`, `[50k:100k]`, `[100k:150k]`, etc. and they won't overlap). When you tested this, did it cause a problem?

Comment: wait really? i was told i needed to add the one for the index. is that not true? that is why i have "50001"

Answer (score 1):

```
cusid2 = [cusid[a:a+50000] for a in range(0, 950000, 50000)]
```

This is a list comprehension basically you will add to your list every element cusid[a: a+50000] for a going from 0 to 950000 (so 1m minus 50k) and iterate with a step of 50k so a will go up by 50k every iteration

Comment: I am new to python, can you please explain this a little bit further? Once i pull the first 50k, i am going to run an analysis and then when that is done, i want to pull the next 50k and run the same analysis until i hit the end of the list.

Comment: cusid2 will contain a list of lists, containing 50000 ids each. You can loop over this structure running your analysis for each element. Thumbs up for this answer for easily switch to generator!

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things to mention:

1. It seems that you're using "data science" stack for your work, good chance you have `numpy` available, please take a look at [`numpy.array_split`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html). You can calculate chunk amount once and use np view machinery. Most probably this is a lot faster than bringing np arrays in to native python lists
2. Idiomatic python approach (IMO) would be leveraging iterators + [islice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

   ```
   from itertools import islice
   # create iterator from your array/list, this is cheap operation
   iterator = iter(cusid)

   # if you want element-wise operations, you can use your chunk in loops or function that require iterations
   # this is really memory-efficient, as you don't put whole chunk in memory
   chunk = islice(iterator, 50000)
   s = sum(chunk)

   # in case you really need whole chunk in memory, just turn isclice into list
   chunk = list(islice(iterator, 50000))
   last_in_chunk = chunk[-1]

   # and you always use same code to consume next chunk from your source
   # without maintaining any counters
   next_chunk = list(islice(iterator, 50000))
   ```

When your `iterator` is exhausted (there's no values left) you will get empty chunk(s). When there's not enough elements to create full chunk, you will get as much as is left there.

Comment: Okay wow, this is amazing. yes, i did install numpy and this a great way to optimize my current code.  for option 2, sorry, i am very new to python....how does this work....so this would go first, iterator = iter(cusid), that make sense, when you say chunk, do you mean the 50k? Im basically taking the first and running an analysis and then when that is done ill export, and pulll the next 50k and run the same analysis until i hit the end of the list.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the logic you're describing. iter(...) gives you iterator, which is "one-way" consumption. And with `islice(iterator, N)` you're saying "give me next N elements". So this is more semantic to your usecase, not "give me from 0th to 50th", but "next 50", no matter if this is beginning or an end